# Can institutions use LaTeX without a license?

Tags: licensing

I refer to the [LaTeX project public license](https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt), which concerns the distribution of LaTeX itself.

What am I concerned with is - **can my institution use LaTeX to typeset (and subsequently distribute) a document, without a license?** For info, we do not plan to release LaTeX code in any form.

If so, what do I need to cite to prove (legally) that this is the case?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, and cannot cite legal arguments.  But I am familiar with both the TeX and LaTeX projects, and know that it is the intent of these projects and the authors of this software that the software can be used by anyone to typeset and distribute documents.  No strings.  (I was for many years part of the TeX support team at the American Mathematical Society, and am also editor of TUGboat, the journal of the TeX Users Group.)

Comment: Questions about legal issues are off topic here, but there is broad agreement that the LPPL applies the software itself, not documents created with it. See [Is a PDF output from a LaTeX document, a "derived work" from the LPPL standard packages?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/82713) for some explicit discussion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns legal issues.